# The identifier "EventApp" in your code signature for EventApp must match your app's Bundle ID

Tags: iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

i'm trying to publish my first iphone app (monotouch) to to the store but i always get the following error after uploading:

The identifier "EventApp" in your code signature for EventApp must match your app's Bundle ID "net.mydomain.myappname".

I have the following settings in monodevelop configured:

- Bundle identifier: net.mydomain.myappname

I have also tried changing this identifier to "net.mydomain.myappname.EventApp" (similar to this screenshot: http://monotouch.net/@api/deki/files/29/=dist-app-settings.png) but then i can't build anymore because monodevelop shows the following error: "Build failed. Array index out of range"

I also had a look in the Info.plist file in the build-output folder. (EventApp.app)
This is what's in there after build:

Bundle name: EventApp
Bundle identifier: net.mydomain.myappname
Executable file: EventApp

Another trial was to rename the project to "myappname" but this didn't also work.

Is there another location somewhere in the *.app package where the identifier could be?
Any ideas how to fix this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you use the correct app store provisioning profile created for the specific bundle id. The bundle id that you used to create the profile should match the bundle id provided in the itunes connect while creating your application there. Use the same bundle id in all the 3 places.
1. Creating provisioning profile
2. Info.plist
3. ItunesConnect

Comment: I have used net.mydomain.myappname in all three places
1) AppId
2) Provisioning Profile
3) ITunes
In all three places i have "net.mydomain.myappname".

What do you mean by "2. Info.plist" ? There is nothing in there (except "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations") => But in the generated *.app there is a Info.plist with the Bundle Identifier: net.mydomain.myappname

Comment: MonoDevelop will build your plist file for you automatically based on your project settings.

Comment: Ok, yes and the content in the plist-file looks good: Bundle identifier: net.mydomain.myappname => So it matches.
So where is this other identifier in the code signature?
The BundleName is EventApp, but this should be no problem?